# How do I get DateTime for the end of the week without Rails?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

How would I get DateTime for the end of the week without Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/). Although the "end of the week" is a little nebulous.

Comment: If you add a new gem dependency to the project to mimic an ActiveSupport feature (I just want to highlight the `end_of_week` method belongs to `ActiveSupport` and not `Rails`, why shouldn't you add `ActiveSupport` itself?

Answer (score 3):

This is the ActiveSupport source code for `end_of_week`

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/date/calculations.rb, line 187
def end_of_week
  days_to_sunday = self.wday!=0 ? 7-self.wday : 0
  result = self + days_to_sunday.days
  self.acts_like?(:time) ? result.end_of_day : result
end
```

It's pretty simple to do the same without ActiveSupport

```
def end_of_week(date)
  days_to_sunday = date.wday!=0 ? 7-date.wday : 0
  result = date + (days_to_sunday * 86400)
  result
end
```

An other alternative is to include ActiveSupport as gem dependency in your project. You don't need to include the full Rails stack to work with dates, just ActiveSupport.